# Propagation of uncertainty - proof that it is minimal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis

I am not really sure if this is the right SE community for this question, but, I swear, I haven't found any better.

The problem is as follows: we have *n* distance sensors placed around a quickly rotating cylinder, the radius of which can grow due to centrifugal loads. They measure the distance to the cylinder 100 times per rotation, and from this data we can then reconstruct numerically the form of the cylinder over time.

Now, I have to prove, that the measurement uncertainty is the smallest, if the sensors are placed symmetrically around the cylinder (for example 0°, 120°, 240°).

I do not expect a complete answer, but maybe a sort of proposal, in which direction I should go.

As you can see below, deriving these equations to calculate where the local minimum of the uncertainty is, seems to be pretty ugly. Is there any better way?

[image]

Those are equations for the radius change and the position of the rotation axis of the cylinder, depending on measured distances and sensor angles.

Comment: I will make one comment about the assumption, that using an integral division of the circle is the optimal way of arranging the sensors. If the rotary motion of the cylinder excites a third harmonic (or a multiple thereof) in the cylinder (which is perfectly possible if the driving motor or transmission has elements with 120 degree symmetry in it), then the placement of the sensors with the same symmetry will pick up an additional systematic error term, which may exceed statistical errors significantly. I would test that possibility very carefully.

Comment: How do you estimate the error? I just make a guess, could it be that the loads vary after longer intervals than T/100, where T is the rotation period? In that case the centrifugal origin of the changes is not relevant, and you need pure statistics, e.g. $<R(\theta)> = \Sigma_i R_i/100$, and $(\Delta_R)^2 = \Sigma_i R_i^2 - <R>^2$, where $\theta$ is measured from a certain marking on the cylinder that marks $\theta = 0$. As the cylinder rotates, the point with some $\theta$ passes in front of the sensors generating $R_1(\theta)$, $R_2(\theta)$, ... $R_{100}(\theta)$ Could this be your case?